# Expected type 'ItemsView', got 'AbstractSet[Tuple[Any, Any]]' instead

Tags: python, typing

I got a type warning from PyCharm:

```
Expected type 'ItemsView', got 'AbstractSet[Tuple[Any, Any]]' instead
```

My code looks like:

```py
def _instancecheck_mapping(mapping: Mapping, type_args: Tuple, type_vars: Dict[str, Any]) -> bool:
    return _instancecheck_items_view(mapping.items(), type_args, type_vars=type_vars)  # here I get the warning


def _instancecheck_items_view(items_view: ItemsView, type_args: Tuple, type_vars: Dict[str, Any]) -> bool:
    key_type, value_type = type_args
    return all(_is_instance(obj=key, type_=key_type, type_vars=type_vars) and
               _is_instance(obj=val, type_=value_type, type_vars=type_vars)
               for key, val in items_view)
```

Do you have any idea how I can fix it?
Edit: I don't want to change the signatures of the functions. I just want to know if the warning tells me that my function call is wrong.

Comment: In what way do you want to fix this? Do you want to change ``mapping.items()`` to match an ``ItemsView``, or ``g`` to take an ``AbstractSet``? Note that views are a [well-defined thing](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-dictionary-view) usually only used by ``dict``.

Comment: I edited the question. I don't want to change the signature of both functions. So yes, I would like to change `mapping.items()` to match an `ItemsView`.

Comment: Well yes, *as written* your function call is wrong as you are supplying an ``AbstractSet`` instead of an ``ItemsView``. A ``typing.Mapping`` does not guarantee to provide views.

Comment: Interesting. I mean, my code works fine. But is there a clean solution that satisfies this warning?

Comment: ``f`` probably does not use a ``typing.Mapping``, just a ``dict``, or ``g`` does not use an ``typing.ItemsView``, just an ``AbstractSet ``. The proper solution is to annotate your function correctly. Whether that specific misuse of annotation is actually the case and whether changing that is correct is impossible to tell from just the question, though.

Comment: The thing is, that I'm writing a type annotation parser and f and g are designed for parsing an `ItemsView` or an `Mapping`. I updated the code in the question.

Comment: It really does not matter what you use that for. The return type of ``Mapping.items`` is not strictly compatible with ``ItemsView``. Either one of these annotations is inadequate (too restrictive/permissive), or your program is broken and you haven't hit that failure path yet.

Comment: Yes, I think the last one is the case. Maybe you can an minimal example of a failing case for my code?
And if I got it right: Not every `Mapping` can be converted to an `ItemsView`?

Comment: Since you only iterate over ``items_view``, the annotation ``Iterable[Tuple[K, V]]`` (with ``K``, ``V`` as ``TypeVar``s) is probably adequate. You do not use any set-like features, let alone view-like features.